# Error using xlsread command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have written in my matlab program:

```
EnergyfromSun = xlsread('C:\Homa\Thesis\Matlab\SC\ASTMG173num.xls');
```

but I got this message:

```
??? No appropriate method, property, or field UsedRange for class
Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library._Chart.

Error in ==> xlsread at 302
        DataRange = Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange;

Error in ==> T2011 at 10
EnergyfromSun = xlsread('C:\Homa\Thesis\Matlab\SC\ASTMG173num.xls');

>>
```

This excel sheet has 2 columns and 2002 rows and I am using matlab 7.11.0 version
Please help me, I am too confused.
Thanks
Homa

>

> I did it but I got the same massage:

```
??? No appropriate method, property, or field UsedRange for class
Interface.Microsoft_Excel_14.0_Object_Library._Chart.

Error in ==> xlsread at 302
        DataRange = Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange;

Error in ==> T2011 at 10
[~,~,EnergyfromSun] = xlsread('C:\Homa\Thesis\Matlab\SC\ASTMG173num.xls');

>>
```

Comment: Try `[~, ~, EnergyfromSun] = xlsread('C:\Homa\Thesis\Matlab\SC\ASTMG173num.xls');` and see what it returns (or if it throws an error too). Edit your question to let us know what occurred. The third output argument of `xlsread` is supposed to just dump the contents of the whole first worksheet in a cell array. It might help us work out what is going wrong. Cheers.

Comment: It's complaining about not being able to get the `UsedRange` property for a chart in the XLS. How about if you remove any charts in your XLS file (Or rather, copy-paste the data you want into a different XLS to test this out)?

Comment: And just out of curiosity; why not just copy-paste (or generate) the data to a CSV and use `textscan` and friends in Matlab? That would derastically improve portability (`xlsread` has many problems on Linux/Mac due to the dependency on the MS COM server (at least, it did on R2010b...))

Comment: Thanks all as Rody said the problem related to the chart that was in my excell file and it has been fixed thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1- I opened MS-EXCEL and made a two column with 2002 rows
2- saved it as Book1.xls on the desktop
3- f = xlsread('Book1.xls'); 
4- and the data is in f

My MATLAB is 2012a, and MS-EXCEL 2007.
Maybe it is related to your address (Path of your excel file)
Or the format that you save your xls file.
can you test a simple xls file, with a normal format and placed on the desktop

and notice this as well:
It works well for me:
On Windows systems with Microsoft Excel software, xlsread reads any file format recognized by your version of Excel.
If your system does not have Excel for Windows, xlsread operates in basic import mode, and reads only XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, and XLTM files.